# Maas and Juju handshake!

Tags: juju, maas, lxc, lxd

Here is my setup;

I have a PowerEdge 2900 running Ubuntu 16.04 server with lxd and Juju installed on it, (this machine hosts 5 containers with very important server apps for our infrastructure).

Then I have another PowerEdge T310, which serves as a MaaS Region and Rack controller. This machine hosts 5 nodes and 68 devices.

My question is: how I can connect Juju with the MaaS controller so I can deploy Juju charms on the machines controlled by MaaS?

Any online guide will help, or if you can point me in the right direction, I will appreciate it.

Regards and love, JC

Answer (score 0):

I think if you run: `juju list-clouds`, then `maas, vmware, azure, etc` should appear.

Then run: `juju add-cloud`

Chose MaaS, with the IP: `x.x.x.x:5240/MAAS`

After that, add the key of the admin user
(via MAAS Gui, 'User' tab, and copy-paste the key from there.)

Then you should: `juju bootstrap maas`

I hope you could solve the problem, if not, tell me...

Thanks

Comment: Hey thank you, I been trying to bootstrap juju I have kvm running on the same server maas, I will back with you later if I found an error, thank you for your answer.